# My ios application is always asking me to Sign In to iTunes Store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an ios Application with IAP feature. It works well. But I encountered a strange issue today. It always show me a message to ask me to "Sign In to iTunes Store" for some reasons. Here is the screenshot:

It always shows this every time when I start the application or resume from background. It even still shows this after I delete and reinstall the application. When I setup breakpoints in my source code. There is no any transaction,payment delegate callbacks. Can anybody tell me what the reason is ? Could it be the problem of Apple IAP Sandbox? (I run the same application in other devices without any problem. I can purchase, restore in Sandbox.)

[image]

Comment: Are you doing receipt verification in your app? I've seen something similar in an app when the receipt wasn't verified correctly (usually only once, though).

Comment: Does it keep coming up if you actually log in?

Comment: I didn't verify the receipt. It will show this again the next time I run the app again or I resume from background no matter I logged in or cancel.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the iTunes Connect test user account?

Comment: has this ever been solved?

Comment: I am having this issue, and I just tried deleting the test user account. So far, no good.

Comment: I just got it to stop. In my case, it was also giving a message something like "You need to sign in to check for downloads." I signed in at that prompt and now, I'm no longer getting this. I did also reboot my iPad.

Answer (score 5):

I've had this problem too a couple of times, it turned out I was stopping processing of transactions before calling finishTransaction on all queued transactions. I was forgetting to finish failed transactions in the particular case.

So, you could try letting your application run once and call finishTransaction for each and every one in your observer delegate like this:

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions 
{
   foreach(SKPaymentTransaction *tr in transactions) [queue finishTransaction:tr];
}
```

i.e. finish every transaction irrespective of transaction state.
After the test run revert to your original handling code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I tried multiple things :

- call finishTransaction for all queued transactions as explained by mpramat (in my case, the array was empty)
- Reboot the iDevice
- Delete the test account in iTunes Connect.

Finally, the only thing that surprisingly worked for me was to delete the app in the iDevice then re-install it via XCode.